# Thank you for the food

Tags: grammar, idiom

I had lunch yesterday in a restaurant and I wanted to say "thank you for the food" (after the meal while paying).

What came out of my mouth was

> 음식이라서 감사합이다

The owner seems to have and understood me.

However I wonder if it was actually correct if not then is the following correct:

> 음식 때문에 감사합니다

But after some research (specifically from Using Korean - A contemporary guide - M. Choi , H.Y. Kwak) I only found.

> 잘 먹었습니다

So I have three:

> 1. 음식이라서 감사합이다
> 2. 음식 때문에 감사합니다
> 3. 잘 먹었습니다

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 음식이라서 감사합니다 => unclear (sounds like "Thank you because it is food")
2. 음식 때문에 감사합니다 => awkward (sounds like "Thank you because of the food")
3. 잘 먹었습니다 => standard way of thanking for food/meal (equivalent to "Thank you, that was a good meal")

#1 and #2 are never said. We usually name the meal or food rather than saying 음식, like 저녁 (dinner), 과일 (fruits), 케이크, etc, and we don't say 이라서 or 때문에 as a reason for thanking.  If you want to mention the meal or food, you can say 저녁(을) 잘 먹었습니다 or 저녁 감사합니다 (better not put anything after 저녁 in this case), using 저녁 as an example.  Having nothing after 저녁 in the latter might look strange but this is how we say it.  Adding 때문에 or 이라서 or a particle like 을, 은, or 이 just butchers it.

The reason for this might be that Korean doesn't have an equivalent of the English "for" used in this context.  Korean has different words and phrases functioning like "for" in different contexts (위해서, 때문에, etc), but it lacks a simple word that expresses "being the basis" for something.  때문에 just doesn't work just as "thank you because of (something)" sounds awkward, and 이라서 is not even comprehensible because it means "because/since it is (something)".

Another common expression you can use in thanking is -아/어서, as in 도와 주셔서 감사합니다, 와 주셔서 고마워요, etc.  But since it a verb phrase, it can't help in your noun-based example.  If you force it on "Thank you for the dinner", you get something like 저녁(을) 주셔서 감사합니다 (Thank you for giving/providing me dinner), which is clear in meaning but sounds verbose and unnatural.  We most commonly just say 저녁 감사합니다.

Comment: Outstanding explanation!